# Can a single Spring Batch application be run on multiple VMs (Linux VMs in their own JVMs)

Tags: spring, virtual-machine, spring-batch

I have a Spring Batch application which will run from the command prompt in the JVM of Unix VM. I am not looking for Remote partitioning or Remote chunking. All I am trying to do is to have the same application run on multiple UNIX VMs in their own JVMs so that thereby I can achieve horizontal scaling of the incoming requests which are huge . is this possible and do I need to have a load balancer ? The application running on multiple VMs will have to read incoming  requests from a DB .

A rest service will put in the requests in  a DB and the Batch application will need to read it from there.

Comment: I think what you want is covered by Spring Cloud, Cloud Task and Data Flow

Comment: This article shows how to register a Spring Batch Job in the Spring Cloud Data Flow: http://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-data-flow-batch-processing